# Reverse proxy replace folder with subdomain?

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to expose Jenkins build status externally via Nginx reverse proxy.  I have created a subdomain `buildstatus.ourcompany.com`, but I don't want the url to be `buildstatus.ourcompany.com/buildstatus/icon?...` so I'm trying the following, without luck:

```
server {
    listen              80;
    server_name         buildstatus.company.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass      $scheme://192.168.1.5:8080/buildStatus/;
    }
}
```

This results in the following error when I visit `buildstatus.companyname.com/icon?job=projectname`:

> ```
> HTTP ERROR 404 Not Found
> URI:  /buildStatus/
> STATUS:   404
> MESSAGE:  Not Found
> SERVLET:  Stapler
> ```

I have confirmed that visiting `192.168.1.5/buildStatus/icon?job=projectname` works as expected.

I tried a couple other things, including one that used `url_rewrite`, but just got other errors.

How can I have `buildstatus.companyname.com/icon?job=projectname` produce the same result as `192.168.1.5/buildStatus/icon?job=projectname`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your configuration sends all requests to `$scheme://192.168.1.5:8080/buildStatus/` URL.

You need to use

```
proxy_pass $scheme://192.168.1.5:8080/buildStatus$request_uri;
```

to add the original URI to the upstream request.